# Initialization of static final fields in Java

Tags: java, initialization, field, final

```
public class Main {
 static final int alex=getc();
 static final int alex1=Integer.parseInt("10");
 static final int alex2=getc();

public static int getc(){
    return alex1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Main m = new Main();
    System.out.println(alex+" "+alex1 +" "+alex2);
  } 
}
```

Can someone tell me why this prints: `0 10 10`? I understand that it's a static final variable and its value shouldn't change but it`s a little difficult to understand how the compiler initializes the fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This situation is covered by [JLS 8.3.2.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2.3) "Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization".

The JLS rules allows the usage in your Question, and state that the first call to `getc()` will return default (uninitialized) value of `alex`.

However, the rules disallow some uses of uninitialized variables; e.g.

```
int i = j + 1;
int j = i + 1;
```

is disallowed.

---

Re some of the other answers.  This is not a case where the Java compiler "can't figure it out".  The compiler is strictly implementing what the Java Language Specification specifies.  (Or to put it another way, a compiler *could* be written to detect the circularity in your example and call it a compilation error.  However, if it did this, it would be rejecting valid Java programs, and therefore wouldn't be a conformant Java compiler.)

---

In a comment you state this:

> ... final fields always must be initialized at compile or at runtime before the object creation.

This is not correct.

There are actually two kinds of `final` fields:

- A so-called "constant variable" is indeed evaluated at compile time.  (A constant variable is a variable *"of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression"* - see JLS 4.12.4.).  Such a field will always have been initialized by the time you access it ... modulo certain complications that are not relevant here.
- Other `final` fields are initialized in the order specified by the JLS, and it *is* possible to see the field's value before it has been initialized.  The restriction on `final` variables is that they must be initialized once and only once *during* class initialization (for a `static`) or *during* object initialization.

---

Finally, this stuff is very much "corner case" behavior.  A typical well-written class won't need to
access a `final` field before it has been initialized.

Answer (score 6):

It's an ordering problem.  Static fields are initialized in the order that they are encountered, so when you call getc() to inititalize the alex variable, alex1 hasn't been set yet.  You need to put initialization of alex1 first, then you'll get the expected result.

Comment: this was an interview question not really a problem, and i was trying to understand why the compiler assigns  0 just because the alex1 field has not been initlialized yet..?because alex1 is final ,and alex takes the place of alex1 =>>alex1 is 0 ?

Comment: static assignments are different than member variables and have no such guarantees.  each static assignment is evaluated in order that the class loader finds it.  so, in your case, it assigns alex first by calling getc().  at this point in time, alex1 hasn't been initialized yet, so 0 is returned.

Comment: ok,thx.Another question.. if it is initialized in a static block the alex1 field,with the value 10,what would the others print? which one is executed  first? the static block or the initialization?

Comment: @Alexx, it is still initialised in the order it appears. Where you place the static block is all that matters.

Comment: again, it would depend on the order.  your `static final int alex1=Integer.parseInt("10");` is really just a shorthand for a static block and will be turned into same by the compiler.

Comment: @stevevis - actually, it is not the class loader that is doing this, it is the intrinsic class initialization mechanism.  (The actual initialization is performed by the classes "<cinit>" pseudo-method.)

Answer (score 4):

Static final fields whose values are not compile-time constant expressions are initialized in order of declaration. Thus when `alex` in being initialized, `alex1` is not initialized yet, so that `getc()` returns default values of `alex1` (`0`).

Note that result will be different (`10 10 10`) in the following case:

```
static final int alex1 = 10;
```

In this case `alex1` is initialized by a compile-time constant expression, therefore it's initialized from the very beginning.

Comment: +1 For compile-time constant expressions. (Why else `Integer.parseInt`?)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about static fields, it just that the compiler cannot workout that you are using a method which can access a field before its initialised.

e.g.

```
public class Main {
    private final int a;

    public Main() {
        System.out.println("Before a=10, a="+getA());
        this.a = 10;
        System.out.println("After a=10, a="+getA());
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Before a=10, a=0
After a=10, a=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Class variables are not necessary to initialize, they are automatically set to their default values. If primitives (like int, short...) it's 0 (zero) for Objects it's `null`. 
Therefore alex1 is set to 0.
Method variables must be initialized, otherwise you will get an compiliation error.

For a better explanation read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: yes, but final fields always must be initialized at compile or at runtime before the object creation.What you sayid applies to normal fields not final ones.ps it works and i sayd before it prints `0 10 10`